# Hibernate sorting ignores null values

Tags: java, hibernate, null

I have two classes: `A` and `B` like this.

```
public Class A {
    public B b;
    // Setter and Getter
}
```

```
public Class B {
    String code;
    // Setter and Getter
}
```

I want to have a list of `A` loaded from database, sorted by `B.code`. But the problem is when an instance of `A` has null value for its `b`, it is ignored, and it is not loaded.

What should be done here? A brief hint would suffice.

**UPDATED**

Here is my code:

```
DetachedCriteria cr = DetachedCriteria.forClass(A.class, "a");
cr.createAlias("a.b", "b");
cr.addOrder(Order.asc("b.code"));
// something like cr.list();
```

Comment: A solution could be to initialize `B b=new B()` and `code=""`

Comment: ORDER BY <column_name> NULL LAST  ??

Comment: I am using criteria and hibernate. Is there a way to have it done by `addOrder` ?

Comment: what is the query your are executing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `createAlias(String associationPath, String alias)` generates an INNER join but here you need a LEFT_OUTER join so use the following instead :

```
cr.createAlias("a.b", "b", CriteriaSpecification.LEFT_JOIN);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this.  I was trying to get optional one-to one's working and couldn't figure out why it kept converting what should have been LEFT joins to INNER joins and I wouldn't get any results for rows that didn't have a child.  From the docs: '[createAlias(String String) is] ... Functionally equivalent to createAlias(String, String, int) using CriteriaSpecification.INNER_JOIN for the joinType.'  See here: [link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)